# Repeated/ Multiple class members of the same data type

Tags: c++, declare

I do not know how many member variables, varX, of the same class instance I need. varX have the same data type. It's impossible to declare them all in .hpp

```cpp
// A.hpp
Class A
{
private:
  T var1; 
  T var2;
  T var3;
  void some_method_using_varX();
  ...
}
```

```cpp
// A.cpp
void A::some_method_using_varX()
{
this->varX = this->someMethod([this]() //varX has to be from the same class instance "this"
  {
    this->varX->otherMethod(); //I also need to access varX inside lambda
  });
}
```

Edit:

the issue is I have no purpose in keeping track of the indexes in the vector. How do i ensure the correct element is accessed in the lamda function?

```cpp
void A::some_method_using_var()
{
    this->vars.push_back(var);
    this ->vars.back() = this->someMethod([this]()
   {
      //when the lambda access the var it may not be the same var 
      //as some_method_using_var() could be called 
      //before the previous lambda finishes
      this->vars.back()->otherMethod(); 
      
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`?

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may be what you want.

Comment: Please note, that while `vector` might be what you want (to little details were given) it is not a one size fits all suggestion. As an example, `vector` can't hold const values.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like instead you should be using a `std::vector`

```
class A
{
private:
  std::vector<T> vars; 
  void some_method_using_var();
};
```

Then you can access a particular one using its index, for example `[0]` is the first variable

```
void A::some_method_using_var()
{
    for (auto& var : vars)
    {
        var = someMethod([&var]()
        {
            var->otherMethod();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i keep all elements at "abstract" level so I do not have to specify index?

Comment: @txlei See my edit, you can capture `var` itself in the lambda so the index isn't needed.

Comment: thanks for following up. In `some_method_using_var()`, a new local variable, `var`, is declared each time. `T var;`. so in the for loop proposed, the var elements are only for previous lambda (a callback function in my case). By specifying the index, my program logic works but like to see if there are other alternatives. Do you know if declaring a `struct` with `var` as member could work? but i do not know how to implement a new struct in `some_method_using_var()` and access the member `var`, could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::vector<T>` type member in the class.